# Bash File modification program. Can not get the options to work Correctly

Tags: bash, getopts

I am still very new to programming in Bash but wanted to make my life easier when it comes to file modification of wordlists. I understand that some of the commands my not be working, but my main problem is getting the options to work correctly. the basic syntax of the program should be "./filemod [option] [argument] [argument]". I was able to get the '-h' option to work and display the different options of the program. I can not get the other options to work correctly, I get no output at all and no error messages to go off of. I am failing to understand what is wrong here and would appreciate any help at all.

Thank you in advance

```
#!/bin/bash

wordlist=$2
outbound=$3

options=alauwcntbjeeEEelpscrcrpRxmh

usage() {
  echo "Script Syntax: [ bash filemod.sh [-options] wordlist outbound file]"
  echo "Options:"
  echo "  -h       Show options"
  echo "  -al      Convert alpha characters on each line in file to lowercase characters"
  echo "  -au      Convert alpha characters on each line in file to uppercase characters"
  echo "  -wc      Create custom wordlist based off the website and print all characters that are 5 or greater"
  echo "  -nt      Clean dictionary/wordlist of newlines and tabs"
  echo "  -bj      Clean Dictionary/wordlist of binary data junk/characters left in file"
  echo "  -e       Extract all lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist"
  echo "  -E       Extract all uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist"
  echo "  -Ee      Extract all uppercase and lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist"
  echo "  -el      Extract strings of a specific length into a new file/wordlist"
  echo "  -p       Pull 100 random samples from wordlist/password for visual analysis"
  echo "  -sc      Print statistics on length of each string and total counts per length"
  echo "  -rc      Remove all Duplicate strings and count how many times they are present; then sort by their count by descending order"
  echo "  -rp      Remove lines that match from both files and only print lines that have not matched from file2"
  echo "  -R       Reverse each line in the file from longest to shortest"
  echo "  -x       Split file into separate files by X number of lines per outfile"
  echo "  -m       Take your 2 files merge and remove duplicate lines and maintain order"
}

while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    h)
      usage
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

extract_lowercase() {
    # Extract all lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
    sed 's/[^a-z]*//g' "$wordlist" > "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    e)
      extract_lowercase
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      extract_lowercase
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

extract_uppercase() {
    # Extract all Uppercae Extract all lowercase and uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
    sed 's/[^A-Z]*//g' "$wordlist" > "$outbound" 
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    E)
      extract_uppercase
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      extract_uppercase
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
extract_lower_upper() {
    # Extract all lowercase and uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
    sed 's/[^a-Z]*//g' "$wordlist" > "$outbound" 
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    Ee)
      extract_lower_upper
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      extract_lower_upper
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
100_random() { 
    # Pull 100 random samples from wordlist/password for visual analysis
    shuf -n 100 "$wordlist"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    p)
      100_random
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      100_random
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
print_stat_length() {
    # Print statistics on length of each string and total counts per length
    awk '{print length}' "$wordlist" | sort -n | uniq -c
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    sc)
      print_stat_length
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      print_stat_length
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
remove_dup_sort_desend() {
    # Remove all Duplicate strings and count how many times they are present; then sort by their count by decending order
    sort -nr | uniq -c "$wordlist" | sort -nr
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    rc)
      remove_dup_sort_desend
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      remove_dup_sort_desend
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
website_scrape() {
    # Create custom wordlist based off the website and print all characters that are 5 or greater
    curl -s -k https://"$wordlist" | grep -oE '[a-z]+' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq | sort -n | grep -E '^.{5,}$' > "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    wc)
      website_scrape
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      website_scrape
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
remove_and_replace() {
    # remove lines that match from both files and only print lines that have not matched from file2
    grep -vwf -f "$wordlist" "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    rp)
      remove_and_replace
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      remove_and_replace
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
merge_and_remove() {
    # Take your 2 files merge and remove duplicate lines and maintain order
    file1=$wordlist
    file2=$outbound
    outbound="merged_no_duplicates.txt"
    # Remove the output file if it already exists
    rm -f "$outbound"
    # Concatenate the contents of file1 and file2 into the outbound file
    cat "$file1" "$file2" >> "$outbound"
    # Sort the outbound file and remove duplicates
    sort "$outbound" | uniq > "$outbound.tmp"
    # Replace the original outbound file with the deduplicated file
    mv "$outbound.tmp" "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    m)
      merge_and_remove
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      merge_and_remove
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
extract_string_length() {
    # Extract strings of a specific length into a new file/wordlist
    awk 'length == 8' "$wordlist" > "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    el)
      extract_string_length
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      extract_string_length
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
convert_lowercase() {
    # Convert alpha characters on each line in file to lowercase characters
    tr "A-Z" "a-z" < "$wordlist" > "$outbound"  
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    al)
      convert_lowercase
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      convert_lowercase
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
convert_uppercase() {
    # Convert alpha characters on each line in file to uppercase characters
    tr "a-z" "A-Z" < "$wordlist" > "$outbound"  
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    au)
      convert_uppercase
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      convert_uppercase
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
split_file() {
    # Split file into separate files by X number of lines per outfile
    split -d -l 3000 "$wordlist" "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    x)
      split_file
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      split_file
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
revsere_longto_short() {
    # Reverse each line in the file from longest to shortest
    awk '{print length,$0} " " $0; }' "$wordlist" | sort -r -n | cut -d ' ' -f2-
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    R)
      revsere_longto_short
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      revsere_longto_short
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
bye_newline_tab() {
    # Clean dictionary/wordlist of newlines and tabs
    cat "$wordlist" | tr -cd "[:print:][/n/t]\n" > "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    nt)
      bye_newline_tab
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      bye_newline_tab
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
bye_binary_junk() {
    # Clean Dictionary/wordlist of binary data junk/characters left in file
    tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < "$wordlist" > "$outbound"
}
while getopts $options opt; do
  case $opt in
    bj)
      bye_binary_junk
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt" >&2
      bye_binary_junk
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

This was another version of the code I tried and could not get it to work. This is not the whole code just a sample ow what was tried. I was mostly testing the '-e' option against a simple wordlist and there is 0 output I can not figure out how to reference the correct option for the syntax in terminal.

```
execute_action(){
    case $1 in
        "-e")
            # Extract all lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
            sed 's/[^a-z]*//g' $wordlist > $oubound 
            ;;

        "-E")
            # Extract all Uppercae Extract all lowercase and uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
            sed 's/[^A-Z]*//g' $wordlist > $oubound 
            ;;

        "-Ee")
            # Extract all lowercase and uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
            sed 's/[^a-Z]*//g' $wordlist > $oubound 
            ;;

        "-p")
            # Pull 100 random samples from wordlist/password for visual analysis
            shuf -n 100 $wordlist
            ;;
        "-sc")
            # Print statistics on length of each string and total counts per length
            awk '{print length}' $wordlist | sort -n | uniq -c
            ;;
        "-rc")
            # Remove all Duplicate strings and count how many times they are present; then sort by their count by decending order
            sort -nr | uniq -c $wordlist | sort -nr
            ;;

        "-wc")
            # Create custom wordlist based off the website and print all characters that are 5 or greater
            curl -s -k https://$wordlist | grep -oE '[a-z]+' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq | sort -n | grep -E '^.{5,}$' > $outbound
            ;;

        "-rp")
            # remove lines that match from both files and only print lines that have not matched from file2
            grep -vwf -f $wordlist $outbound
            ;;

        "-m")
            # Take your 2 files merge and remove duplicate lines and maintain order
            file1=$wordlist
            file2=$outbound
            outbound="merged_no_duplicates.txt"
            # Remove the output file if it already exists
            rm -f $outbound
            # Concatenate the contents of file1 and file2 into the outbound file
            cat $file1 $file2 >> $outbound
            # Sort the outbound file and remove duplicates
            sort $outbound | uniq > $outbound.tmp
            # Replace the original outbound file with the deduplicated file
            mv $outbound.tmp $outbound
            ;;
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Keep a bookmark to https://www.shellcheck.net/. I don't program bash every day myself, but the site helps lint check your program for syntax issues and other potential problems. Has helped me quite often when I get stuck with a script.

Comment: See the "Before asking about problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" sections of the ['bash' tag wiki - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: `getopts` can't process multi-character options like `-al`.

Comment: See [How can I debug a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/4154375).

Comment: Why do you have multiple `while getopts` loops? The first one will exit the script for any option other than `-h`. You should just have one loop that sets variables depending on all the options that are given. Then the rest of the script can check the variables.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, `getopts` cannot process short options with multiple characters.  You also can't execute `getopts` multiple times because `getopts` will increase the next option index every time it's invoked.

You can instead use a simple option and argument parsing operation like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

worldlist= outbound=
shopt -s extglob || exit 1 # Make sure extglob matching is available

usage() {
  echo "Script Syntax: [ bash filemod.sh [-options] wordlist outbound_file]"
  echo "Options:"
  echo "  -h       Show options"
  echo "  -al      Convert alpha characters on each line in file to lowercase characters"
  echo "  -au      Convert alpha characters on each line in file to uppercase characters"
  echo "  -wc      Create custom wordlist based off the website and print all characters that are 5 or greater"
  echo "  -nt      Clean dictionary/wordlist of newlines and tabs"
  echo "  -bj      Clean Dictionary/wordlist of binary data junk/characters left in file"
  echo "  -e       Extract all lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist"
  echo "  -E       Extract all uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist"
  echo "  -Ee      Extract all uppercase and lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist"
  echo "  -el      Extract strings of a specific length into a new file/wordlist"
  echo "  -p       Pull 100 random samples from wordlist/password for visual analysis"
  echo "  -sc      Print statistics on length of each string and total counts per length"
  echo "  -rc      Remove all Duplicate strings and count how many times they are present; then sort by their count by descending order"
  echo "  -rp      Remove lines that match from both files and only print lines that have not matched from file2"
  echo "  -R       Reverse each line in the file from longest to shortest"
  echo "  -x       Split file into separate files by X number of lines per outfile"
  echo "  -m       Take your 2 files merge and remove duplicate lines and maintain order"
  exit 0 # Probably better be a nonzero like 2
}

die() {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
  exit "${2-1}"
}

extract_lowercase() {
  # Extract all lowercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
  sed 's/[^a-z]*//g' "$wordlist" > "$outbound" || die "Failed to extract lowercase strings."
}

extract_uppercase() {
  # Extract all Uppercae Extract all lowercase and uppercase strings from each line and output to wordlist
  sed 's/[^A-Z]*//g' "$wordlist" > "$outbound" || die "Failed to extract uppercase strings."
}

...

main() {
  local -A opts=() || die "Unable to initialize associative array."
  local names=()

  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
    -h)
      usage
      ;;
    -@(al|au|wc|nt|bj|e|E|Ee|el|p|sc|rc|rp|R|x|m)
      opts[${1:1}]=.
      ;;
    --)
      names+=("${@:2}")
      break
      ;;
    -*)
      die "Invalid option: $1"
      ;;
    *)
      names+=("$1")
      ;;
    esac

    shift
  done

  [[ ${#names[@]} -ne 2 ]] && die "Invalid number of names specified."
  [[ ${#opt[@]} -eq 0 ]] && die "No operation option specified."
  [[ ${#opt[@]} -gt 1 ]] && die "Only one option can be specified."

  wordlist=${names} outbound=${names[1]}

  case ${!opts[*]} in
  e) extract_lowercase ;;
  E) extract_uppercase ;;
  ...
  esac
}

main "$@"
```

The script should also be easy to modify so it can allow multiple operations to happen at once, probably by repeated use of command substitution and heredocs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I am going to do some research and try to implement this into this into my code.